# R graphics: How to plot a sequence of characters (pure categorical time series)

Tags: r, plot, time-series, categorical-data

I have a matrix in which each element is a pure categorical variable "a","b","c","d",... Each column of the matrix is a chronological entry and now I want to plot the matrix by row and I hope the y-axis is the sequence of characters.

Here is the original matrix:

[image: Graph with legend]

Here is what I wanted the plot to be:
[image: Graph with legend]

The red plot is first row of the matrix and the blue plot is the fifth.

I have tried some existing packages but mostly they require me to transfer the categorical variables to numerical variables. So I wonder if anyone could help me with this. Many thanks!

Comment: if you could give us a table we can use that would be easier to help. For instance do `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your prompt reply, I did not figure out how to add pictures or tables, I wonder if I can send the table to your email? Many thanks!

Comment: By the way, can you see the pictures (through the link in my post)?

Comment: I edited your post (it must be validated before been displayed) so the images will be displayed, but for the moment we can see them by clicking on the link. We don't need the full database, juste write `dput(head(data,n=20))` (if data is the name of your database) and copy past the result that appears on your R console.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your data, I have to generate some toy one, called `mat`, with 5 rows and 10 columns, filled with `letters[1:7]`.

```
set.seed(0); mat <- matrix(sample(letters[1:7], 5 * 10, TRUE), nrow = 5)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,] "g"  "b"  "a"  "f"  "f"  "b"  "c"  "f"  "c"  "d"  
#[2,] "b"  "g"  "b"  "d"  "g"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "f"  
#[3,] "c"  "g"  "b"  "f"  "b"  "a"  "e"  "f"  "e"  "a"  
#[4,] "e"  "e"  "e"  "g"  "e"  "c"  "d"  "a"  "f"  "d"  
#[5,] "g"  "e"  "c"  "c"  "a"  "g"  "b"  "f"  "d"  "f"
```

Basically you need first re-represent you character matrix `mat` with integers.

```
## flatten your object into a vector first
if (is.matrix(mat)) v <- as.character(mat)
if (is.data.frame(mat)) v <- as.character(unlist(mat, use.names = FALSE))
lev <- sort(unique(v))    ## sorted unique labels

## re-representation
mat_int <- matrix(match(v, lev), nrow = nrow(mat))
## or: mat_int <- matrix(as.integer(factor(v, levels = lev)), nrow = nrow(mat))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    7    2    1    6    6    2    3    6    3     4
#[2,]    2    7    2    4    7    3    4    5    6     6
#[3,]    3    7    2    6    2    1    5    6    5     1
#[4,]    5    5    5    7    5    3    4    1    6     4
#[5,]    7    5    3    3    1    7    2    6    4     6
```

Then you just plot (the whole or some rows of) this matrix using `matplot`. Disable the y-axis first then add it later using `axis` so that you can customize axis labels.

```
## this plots the whole matrix
matplot(t(mat_int), yaxt = "n", type = "l", xlab = "time", ylab = "category")
axis(2, seq_along(lev), labels = lev)

## this plots 1st and 5th rows
matplot(t(mat_int)[, c(1,5)], yaxt = "n", type = "l", xlab = "time", ylab = "category")
axis(2, seq_along(lev), labels = lev)
```

Plot of the selected two rows:

[image]

Comment: Hi Zheyuan, you code works just perfectly awesome!! I'd like to thank you so much!